# How to create a user using microstrategy SDK in java (External Security Module)

Tags: microstrategy

My goal is to create user using microstrategy SDK and assign filters and groups to the user.

1. I have  a java class CreateUser & SSOESM from SDK. Do I have to create a plugin of the create user class and deploy it in microstrategy intelligence server.

   ```
   public class CreateUser {
       public static WebIServerSession sessionInfo;
       public static final String loginName = "NewUser";
       public static final String password= "";
       public static final String fullName= "New User";
       public static final String description="New User Created Programattically";

       /*  The following information is required to login and manipulate the User management API */
       /* iServerName is the IServer we are connecting to */
       public static final String iServerName = "localhost";
       /* projectName is the project name we are connecting to */
       public static final String projectName = "";
       /* loginName is the user name we use to login the project */
       public static final String adminLoginName = "administrator";
       /* loginPasswd is the password we use to login the project */
       public static final String adminLoginPasswd = "";

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           sessionInfo = getServerSession(iServerName, projectName, adminLoginName, adminLoginPasswd);

           UserBean user = null;
           try {
               //Instantiate a new user
               user = (UserBean)BeanFactory.getInstance().newBean("UserBean");
               user.setSessionInfo(sessionInfo);
               user.InitAsNew();

               //Fetch properties for the user
               WebUser ua = (WebUser) user.getUserEntityObject();
               WebStandardLoginInfo loginInfo = ua.getStandardLoginInfo();

               //Set basic user information
               ua.setLoginName(loginName);
               ua.setFullName(fullName);
               user.getObjectInfo().setDescription(description);
               loginInfo.setPassword(password);

               //Set other properties
               Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
               cal.set(2012, 11, 21);
               Date d = cal.getTime();

               loginInfo.setPasswordExpirationDate(d);  //Password expires on November 21, 2012
               loginInfo.setPasswordExpirationFrequency(90); //90 days to expire
               loginInfo.setPasswordExpiresAutomatically(true); //If set to false, password never expires
               loginInfo.setStandardAuthAllowed(true); //The user can log in using standard auth

               user.save();
           } catch (WebBeanException ex) {
               System.out.println("Error creating a user: " + ex.getMessage());
           }
       }

       public static WebIServerSession getServerSession(String serverName, String Project, String loginName, String password) {
           WebIServerSession sessionInfo = null;
           try {
               WebObjectsFactory woFact = WebObjectsFactory.getInstance();
               sessionInfo = woFact.getIServerSession();

               sessionInfo.setServerName(serverName);
               sessionInfo.setProjectName(Project);
               sessionInfo.setLogin(loginName);
               sessionInfo.setPassword(password);
               sessionInfo.setApplicationType(EnumDSSXMLApplicationType.DssXmlApplicationCustomApp);
               //Create a new session
               sessionInfo.getSessionID();
           } catch (WebObjectsException ex) {
               System.out.println("Error creating a sesion");
           }

           return sessionInfo;
       }
   }
   ```

My goal is when a user try to logon the user should be created on the fly using the sdk classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to create a plugin and configure the plugin to use the java class you have created as an ESM.

https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDZ_World2015/docs/projects/WebSDK/output/HTML5/Content/topics/esm/specifying_the_custom_esm_to_use.htm

With that said its important to understand that the actions you are performing are very expensive. They may degrade the user experience if you are attempting to provide a fast SSO experience. Depending on the implementation you have it may be better to create a custom task, which can be fired when the user authenticates with the third party application. This task can perform all the actions you are describing, and then return a session state. Which can be used in any subsequent connections to MicroStrategy Web.